# Getting a weird Error in C LinkedList Programm

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Why does this code give me "unknown type name listelement" as error?

```
struct listelement
  {
    int wert;
    listelement *next;
};
```

Comment: Because it is not a known type. `struct listelement` would be known, or you can `typedef` it.

Answer (score 3):

`struct listelement` and (missing) typedef `listelement` are two different things (name spaces).  Add the typedef before your struct declaration:

```
typedef struct listelement listelement;
```

or change your struct to:

```
struct listelement {
    int wert;
    struct listelement *next;
};
```